# Why the same URL gives different results?

Tags: web-scraping

On the following page, the number 2, 3 ... at the bottom all point to the same URL. Yet, the different tables will be shown. Does anybody know what specific techniques are used here? How to extract information in these tables using raw HTTP request (I prefer not to use a headless browser to do so)? Thanks.

https://services27.ieee.org/fellowsdirectory/home.html#results_table

Answer (score 1):

It is using Javascript (AJAX) to make HTTP calls to the server.
If you inspect the Network activity in the Developer tools you will see calls to the following URL: `https://services27.ieee.org/fellowsdirectory/getpageresultsdesk.html`.

They send data from Javascript:

```
selectedJSON: {"alpha":"ALL","menu":"ALPHABETICAL","gender":"All","currPageNum":1,"breadCrumbs":[{"breadCrumb":"Alphabetical Listing "}],"helpText":"Click on any of the alphabet letters to view a list of Fellows."}
inputFilterJSON: {"sortOnList":[{"sortByField":"fellow.lastName","sortType":"ASC"}],"typeAhead":false}
pageNum: 2
```

You can see the `pageNum` property. This is how they request a specific page of results.

Comment: Thanks. What tools did you use to figure the details?

Answer (score 1):

When you click the number buttons, some Javascript code makes an AJAX POST request to https://services27.ieee.org/fellowsdirectory/getpageresultsdesk.html;jsessionid=yoursessionid with formData including `pageNum: 3` and some other formatting parameters. The server responds with the HTML block of table rows that get loaded into the page. You can look at the requests on that webpage in your browser's network inspector (in the developer tools) to see exactly what HTTP requests are happening.

Comment: Thanks. What tools did you use to figure out the details?

Answer (score 1):

The link has an onclick handler that changes the href onclick. Go to 
https://services27.ieee.org/fellowsdirectory/home.html#results_table
In the console, enter:
window.location=getDetailProfileUrl('lOH1bDxMyI1CCIxo5ODlGg==');
This redirects to Aarons, Jules.
Now go back and enter window.location=getDetailProfileUrl('JJuL3J00kHdIUozoVAgKdg==');
This opens Aarts, Ronald.
Basically, when the link is clicked, the JavaScript changes the url of the link.

To extract them using php, use the file_get_contents() function.

```
echo file_get_contents('https://services27.ieee.org/fellowsdirectory/home.html#results_table');
```

That will print out the page. Now scrape it with JavaScript.

```
echo "<script>console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.name'));</script>";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wait, Jess Kennedy is a genius.

Comment: https://services27.ieee.org/fellowsdirectory/getpageresultsdesk.html;jsessionid=yoursessionid

Comment: What "console" do you refer to in "In the console,"? The first echo just download the webpage. How to use the second echo command. Could you show me the complete code and how to run it?

Comment: The second echo command echoes a JavaScript block. In the script, the code logs document.querySelectorAll('.name') in the console. document.querySelectorAll('.name') gets all the elements in a class called "name", which returns with all the html blocks containing each user's name. That can be seen in the console...